# Sending data to "View" from "Controller"

Tags: grails, groovy

In my controller class  have the following code

```
class MyController {

    def flickrService

    def index = {
        def data = flickrService.search {
            tags 'tag,tag2,tag3'
            page 3
            perPage 14 // Look ma!
        }
        [urls:data.urls,page:data.page,pages:data.pages]
    }

}
```

I have also created an index.gsp file.
As I am new to groovy grails - i could not figure it out how to access data returned by flickrservice in the view. Can I just access "data" defined above in the index view or I need to set it in the controller before I can loop through the returned data? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, now you can access data from the view, for example,in index.gsp:

```
<html><head>Test</head><body>${urls} <br/> ${page} </body></html>
```

Generally saying, grails return the last value in function by default, so if you want to access many data, you can do like this:

```
class MyController {

    def flickrService

    def index = {
        def data = ...
        def data1 = ...
        def data2 = ...

        // Here's the return result:
            [view_data:data,view_data1:data1, view_data2:data2]
    }

}
```

Then you can access ${view_data},${view_data1},${view_data2} in view.

Comment: Thanks I just figuredit out.. Could you help me with another query .. in above if I have max=10 above the "def data" but inside "def index" hw to pass this value to perPage option?? I tried "perpage max" but throws an error ?

Comment: @Kay can you post this as a separate question and I'll try to help

Comment: @Kay: you must define the "max" variable before using: def max = 10

Comment: @Long .. maybe yes but I actually tried params.max and it worked (max only didnt work) thank you

Comment: @Kay: you can use params.max, so max is already set in params of the request. I think you should reference this link: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html , at 6.1.2 to understand the problem more clearly.